# How do I test a functional interface that is passed to a mocked object [Mockito, Spring]

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a `MailService` class that I would like to unit test. It invokes the [JavaMailSender#send](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html#send-org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator-) method which accepts a [MimeMessagePreparator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessagePreparator.html) functional interface as an argument. The `JavaMailSender` class will then call [MimeMessagePreparator#prepare](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessagePreparator.html#prepare-javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage-).

However, because the `JavaMailSender` object will be mocked for this unit test, the `prepare` method will not be invoked in my test. What is the proper way to unit test the `MimeMessagePreparator` when its method is only called from within a mocked object?

I am aware that I can create the `MimeMessage` separately and pass it to the `send` method as an argument, but if that weren't an option, is there a way to test the above?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use [spy](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Spy.html) instead of mock?

You can spy on the JavaMailSender instance and then verify if the MimeMessagePreparator#prepare has been called.

Comment: And then stub the method inside the JavaMailSender that executes the send? I will try that. Thanks for the suggestion.